# How can I write the transformation in a cleaner way

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a method which takes a list of object (Widget) -- which contains some properties (header) and nested list(component). I want to flatten the list into a single list and have the below code for same:

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    fun flatten(fatList: Single<List<Widget>>) {
        val flatList: MutableList<IUiData> = mutableListOf()

        fatList.map {
            Observable.fromIterable(it).map { widget ->
                if (widget.header.isNotEmpty()) {
                    flatList.add(ProductHeaderUi(widget.header))
                }
                widget.componentList.map { component ->
                    when (component.type) {
                        TILE_TEXT -> {
                            flatList.add(HeaderUi(component))
                        }
                        TILE_IMAGE -> {
                            flatList.add(ImageTileUi(component))
                        }
                        TILE_FOOTER -> {
                            flatList.add(FooterUi(component))
                        }
                        UNKNOWN -> {
                            //Do Nothing 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I intend to return a Single of List:  `Single<MutableList<IUiData>>` from this method, this purpose can be served right now, but I am looking for a cleaner way

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to convert a Single into a MutableList, because you have to wait for the data to be produced. You could turn it into a `Single<MutableList<IUiData>>`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes my bad, it should be a `Single<MutableList<IUiData>>`

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using both Rx's Observable `map` and Kotlin's Iterable `map` in an unintended way. They are for converting one type to another, not for iterating something.

You've also nested an unnecessary Observable iterable inside the outer-most map function.

You only need to map the output of the Single. Inside the `map` function, you iterate (not `map`) the original List to pull out the data you need for the MutableList.

I'm an Rx novice and didn't check this, so sorry about any syntax errors.

```
fun flatten(fatList: Single<List<Widget>>): Single<MutableList<IUData>> = fatList.map { widgetList ->
    val flatList: MutableList<IUiData> = mutableListOf()
    for (widget in widgetList) {
        if (widget.header.isNotEmpty()) {
            flatList.add(ProductHeaderUi(widget.header))
        }
        for (component in widget.componentList) { 
            when (component.type) {
                TILE_TEXT -> flatList.add(HeaderUi(component))
                TILE_IMAGE -> flatList.add(ImageTileUi(component))
                TILE_FOOTER -> flatList.add(FooterUi(component))
                // Else do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    flatList
}
```

But in keeping with typical Rx chaining syntax, I would make it an extension function, so I'd have to first line like this. Then you can put it right in the middle of an Rx call chain:

```
fun Single<List<Widget>>.flatten(): Single<MutableList<IUData>> = map { widgetList ->
```

You can also do this in a more concise, functional, but less efficient way by using Kotlin's `flatMap`:

```
fun Single<List<Widget>>.flatten(): Single<MutableList<IUData>> = map {
    it.flatMap { widget ->
        listOfNotNull(widget.header.takeIf(Header::isNotEmpty)?.let(::ProductHeaderUi))
        +
        widget.componentList.mapNotNull { component ->            
           when (component.type) {
                TILE_TEXT -> HeaderUi(component)
                TILE_IMAGE -> ImageTileUi(component)
                TILE_FOOTER -> FooterUi(component)
                else -> null
            }
        }.toMutableList()
}
```

...where `Header` is whatever type `widget.header` uses.